# Show for the complex number $z=\frac{1-t^2+2it}{1+t^2},|z|=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Show for the complex number $$z=\frac{1-t^2+2it}{1+t^2},|z|=1$$

for all real values of $t$.

How should I  prove it? Hope there's someone to explain this type of question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Euler_and_Weierstrass

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Factorize the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that $1-t^2+2it=(1+it)^2$. Then use: $\left\lvert \frac{a}{b} \right\rvert=\frac{|a|}{|b|}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$|z|^2=z\bar z=\frac{(t-i)^2(t+i)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac{(t^2+1)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}=1\implies |z|=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$1-t^2+2it=(1+it)^2$, thus $|1-t^2+2it=|1+it|^2=1+t^2$.